# nullable datetimes and null dates still display as 1/1/0001

Tags: datetime, jqgrid, asp.net-mvc-4, nullable

In my jqGrid, I want to have empty values in my grid...

Instead I am getting 1/1/0001

my model types for the dateTime are all nullable.

Am I missing something???

this is the code...

```
public DateTime? DischargeDateTime { get; set; }
```

What do you guys recommend?

```
        tableToGrid("#frTable", {
            cmTemplate: { sortable: false },
            caption: '@TempData["POPNAME"]' + ' Population',
            height: '400',
            gridview: true,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            autowidth: true,
            colNames: ['Edit',
                   'MRN',
                   'Hospital Fin',
                   'First Name',
                   'Last Name',
                   'Date of birth',
                   'Completed Pathway',
                   'Completed Pathway Reason',
                   'PCP Appointment',
                   'Specialist Appointment',
                   'Admit Date',
                   'Discharge Date',
                   'Discharge Disposition',
                   'Discharge To',
                   'Discharge Advocate Call',
                   'Home Healthcare',
                   'Safe Landing Accepted',
                   'PCP Name',
                   'PCP Phone',
                   'PCP Appointment Location',
                   'Specialist Name',
                   'Specialist Phone',
                   'Specialist Appointment Location',
                   'Comments',
                   'Patient Room Phone',
                   'Phone',
                   'Payor',
                   'MRN Type'
                   ],
            colModel: [
                   { name: 'Edit', width: 95, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'MRN', width: 125, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Hospital_Fin', width: 145, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'First_Name', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Last_Name', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Date_of_birth', width: 145, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Completed_Pathway', width: 125, align: 'left', editOptions: {value:"1:Yes;0:No"} },
                   { name: 'Completed_Pathway_Reason', width: 165, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'PCP_Appointment', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Specialist_Appointment', width: 125, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Admit_Date', width: 185, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Discharge_Date', width: 185, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Discharge_Disposition', width: 155, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Discharge_To', width: 85, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Discharge_Advocate_Call', width: 155, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Home_Health_Care_Accepted', width: 105, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Safe_Landing_Accepted', width: 165, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'PCP_Name', width: 85, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'PCP_Phone', width: 85, align: 'left' }, // formatter: formatPhoneNumber,
                   { name: 'PCP_Appointment_Location', width: 185, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Specialist_Name', width: 195, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Specialist_Phone', width: 135, align: 'left' }, //, formatter: formatPhoneNumber
                   { name: 'Specialist_Appointment_Location', width: 185, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Comments', width: 185, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Patient_Room_Phone', width: 135, align: 'left' }, //, formatter: formatPhoneNumber
                   { name: 'Phone', width: 125, align: 'left' }, //, formatter: formatPhoneNumber
                   { name: 'Payor', width: 155, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'MRN_Type', width: 135, align: 'left' }
                   ]
        });
```

There are indeed several nulls in my database that come back...  Not sure why this doesn't work...

Currently trying a UIHint...

```
@if (Model == null){
    <text></text>
}else{
    <text></text>
}
```

except now everything is being displayed incorrectly

Comment: Can you post a little more context? How do you fill and serialize your models for the gird, how does the relevant parts of your jqGrid setup looks like? Have you checked in fiddler/firebug what data do you get from the server?

Comment: I know I get back some null or empty dates from the server... Ill post my jqGrid setup... It is a tableToGrid call...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I know what I was doing wrong.  In my repository layer, I forgot I had a method that would take the string dates that were being pulled pack, parsed, and if the value was null I would set the minimum date.

I have now changed that so that it returns a null, or a parsed date...

```
    public static DateTime? ValueOrMin(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) return null;
        return DateTime.Parse(value);
    }
```

Thanks.